# json result to array and get result

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I have simple API call for themoviedb.org and I get results by external id (imdb_id), but I can't parse and get correct value.

I just want get value of ID --> `[id] => 18773`

So how I can get stored only themoviedb ID from API?

My code:

```
$url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/".$imdbId."?api_key=$apikey&language=en-US&external_source=imdb_id";

$content = file_get_contents($url, false);

// Tried 
$json = json_decode($content, true);

echo $json['id']; // return nothing?


// Testing (check below array return)
$result = array_values(json_decode($content, true));
print("<pre>".print_r($result,true)."</pre>");
```

Array from `$result`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [adult] => 
                    [backdrop_path] => /iSaKc4Nu7hTQDAvJigUVmNwTkj6.jpg
                    [genre_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 27
                            [1] => 9648
                            [2] => 53
                        )

                    [id] => 18773
                    [original_language] => en
                    [original_title] => Doppelganger
                    [overview] => A woman moves from NYC to LA after a murder, in which she is implicated. She is followed by what is apparently her evil alter- ego. She moves into a room for rent by a writer, and he begins having an affair with her, but after some strange things happen, he's not so sure if the affair is with her or her doppelganger.
                    [poster_path] => /kdMJhjqAlwJekpp8jGu6Lk3Tfy6.jpg
                    [release_date] => 1993-03-01
                    [title] => Doppelganger
                    [video] => 
                    [vote_average] => 5
                    [vote_count] => 56
                    [popularity] => 5.931
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: How does the JSON `$content` look like?

Comment: `$result[0][0]['id'];` -- `$result[1][0]['id'];` -- `$result[2][0]['id'];`  etc etc etc

Comment: $json[0][0]['id']

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/find/find-by-id you can get the id value by something like this `$json['movie_results'][0]['id']`.

But as you can see, the object `movie_results` is an array so you may have there more than one result or even no results.

So here are some tips what you should consider in your code:

1. What to do if there are more than one results?
2. What to do if there are no result at all?

If there is only one result you can safely get the ID.